# What's the correct action for pressing a key?

Tags: dynamic, interactive, keyboard

Consider the following code:

```
timesXpressed = 0;
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> timesXpressed++}]
Dynamic[timesXpressed]
```

It counts the number of times the key `x` is pressed. However, in intercepting the key presses, they're no longer actually typed in the notebook. I suspect adding an additional action to type `x` in the notebook when the key is down might fix this, but I don't know such an action.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior on v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Only when "x" is pressed in the notebook does it change the `timesXpressed`. Please run `$Version` and include this information.

Comment: `ref/NotebookEventActions`/`Details`: The default behavior can be changed by including rules for PassEventsDown or PassEventsUp in the list given as the setting for NotebookEventActions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
timesXpressed = 0;
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> (timesXpressed++; 
     FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "x"]])}]
Dynamic[timesXpressed]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to do logical combinations on these events, for example an action when `{"KeyDown", "x"} or {"KeyDown", "X"}` ?

Comment: Just add another `Keydown` action, e.g. `NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> (timesX... , "x"]), {"KeyDown", "X"} :> (timesX... , "X"])}`